# sed match all brackets/braces open/close in character class

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to use gnu sed to add a new line character after each square brace `[`/`]`  or squiggly bracket `{`/`}`, but the closing brace `]` is causing trouble:

```
$ sed 's,\([\[\]{}]\),\1\n,g' test.json

{ "file1": {hello world}, "file2": [1,2,3,4,] }
```

matches no characters. If I ommit the closing brace, it works matches everything (but the closing brace):

```
$ sed 's/\([\[{}]\)/\1\n/g' test.json
{
 "file1": {
hello world}
, "file2": [
1,2,3,4,] }
```

What can I do to escape the closing brace to get this regex to match?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Are you sure you're not re-inventing JSON pretty printing, like `jq . <<< '{ "file1": {hello world}, "file2": [1,2,3,4,] }'`? Side note: your JSON is invalid, there is a trailing comma.

Answer (score 3):

About bracket expressions, the [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05) says:

> The <right-square-bracket> ( ']' ) shall lose its special meaning and represent itself in a bracket expression if it occurs first in the list (after an initial <circumflex> ( '^' ), if any). Otherwise, it shall terminate the bracket expression,...

and,

> The special characters '.', '*', '[', and '\' ( <period>, <asterisk>, <left-square-bracket>, and <backslash>, respectively) shall lose their special meaning within a bracket expression.

So in this case, you don't need to escape anything in the bracket expression, just make `]` the first in it. E.g:

```
$ sed 's/[][{}]/&\n/g' <<EOF
{ "file1": {hello world}, "file2": [1,2,3,4,] }
EOF

{
 "file1": {
hello world}
, "file2": [
1,2,3,4,]
 }

$
```